Implication about the hypotenuse of a triangle being multiple of $\sqrt{2}$
If the hypotenuse of a triangle is a multiple of the square root of two, does it necessarily imply that the two legs of the triangle are equal? What about if both sides are integers?
If $a^2+b^2 = 2k^2$, does this mean $a=b$? I know that if $a=b$ then hypotenuse would be $\sqrt{2}a$... But I can't figure out the reverse implication.
I might be overthinking this.

If $a^2+b^2=c^2$, then $(a-b)^2+(a+b)^2=2c^2$

This is useful working with pytagorean triples if we require a, b and c to be integers. Thanks

Or you could treat it as $m^2+n^2=(k\sqrt2)^2$.  The example in the accepted answer is $(4-3)^2+(4+3)^2=2(5^2)$.

Even if the two legs of a right triangle have integer lengths, and the hypotenuse is an integer multiple of $\sqrt2$, that does not guarantee that the two legs are equal. One example is the right triangle with legs $1$ and $7$: the length of the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{1^2 + 7^2} = \sqrt{50} = 5\sqrt2$.
(Also, $a^2 + b^2 = k\sqrt2$ is the wrong way to encode this algebraically. You want $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = k\sqrt2$, or $a^2+b^2 = 2k^2$.)
